# Convert *char or char to bits

Tags: c, memory, bitmap

How do I convert * char or char to bits ?
For example:
Here 's my declarations

```
uint64_t blocks[64];
char * word = "hello";
```

How do I store the word hello in bytes inside blocks[0] ?
I tried this

```
int e;
int a = strlen(word);
for (e = 0; e < a; e++) {
    blocks[0] |= !!word[e] >> 8;
}
```

Also, how will I reverse the process?

Comment: What about `memcpy(blocks, word, strlen(word))` ?

Comment: I need them in bit form, like 00100101

Comment: `blocks[0] |= !!word[e] >> 8;` What do you think this does? I am not sure what your expected output is. Your whole loop can be reduced to the last iteration only. And how is this related to bit maps. @_@.

Comment: ie 'h' -> 0x68 -> 01101000(10) , `blocks[0] = 1101000;`

Comment: Yes, and then I have to store it inside blocks[0].

Comment: What is it you really want to do? Store a series of integers representing the bits that represent a character or sequence of characters? E.g. 'K' is 0x4B in ASCII, stored as an array of ints [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
Or copy the bits in a `char` into a `uint64_t`?

Comment: I want to copy the bits in a char into a uint64_t.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to copy the bits in a char into a uint64_t."

Try using [memcpy](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#memcpy):

```
void * memcpy(void * dst, const void * src, size_t n)
```

e.g.

```
memcpy(blocks, word, strlen(word));
```

---

**More than one string**

Regarding your comment which I interpret to be about copying more than one string:

`memcpy` copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dst`, so if we want to copy several strings in succession, we need to make sure calls to `memcpy` have `src` set to the end of the last string we copied, assuming we want to copy "hello" and then "world" into `blocks` and end up with the bytes that represent "helloworld".

```
// if you have a char** words and uint64_t blocks[64]; or similar
uint64_t blocks[64];
const char *words[2] = { "hello", "world" };

size_t offset = 0, len;
int num_words = sizeof words / sizeof words[0], n;
for (n = 0; n < num_words && offset < sizeof blocks; ++n) {
  len = strlen(words[n]);
  memcpy(((void *)blocks) + offset, words[n], len); // note the void * cast
  offset += len;
}
```

This should be easily adaptable to a situation where you are reading in the strings rather than having an array of array of chars.

---

**Getting a string back again**

To take `blocks` and get a `char *` with all the bytes in it, we need to remember that strings in C are null terminated, so if we want to treat the result as a string, it needs a null on the end. The last `offset` you have once you are done copying (from above) could be used to add this.

```
char new_word[100];
memcpy(new_word, blocks, sizeof new_word);
new_word[offset] = 0;
```

We don't have to copy the data to treat this as a `char *`, by the way; We could just cast...

```
char * new_word = (char *)blocks;
```

...but remember that if you do this, modifying `new_word` will also modify `blocks`.

Comment: Will this work if I want to add more chars into the same uint64_t?
Because I want to completely fill them out before moving to next block[1]

Comment: As in, after you copy "hello", can you copy more chars as well? Yes, you can, but you need to make sure not to overwrite what you already copied in.

Comment: How do I do this? Do memcpy overwrite automatically, or will it just do it after all the 8byte as been occupied in my 64bit block?

Comment: memcpy will overwrite, so you need to move the location that memcpy _starts writing at_ along as you go. I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks!
I managed to do it finally.
Is there anyway to reverse the process?

Comment: Do you want each word out separately? Or all together? And you should probably open that as a separate question, or else edit this one to be clearer and include a request for the reverse process.

Comment: I will do so now. And all together.

Comment: There you go, see the latest update. Also make sure you don't forget the `void *` cast in the first part; I forgot to put it in before.